# SQLAlchemy merge values with NULL

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an entity `Car` that inherits `declarative_base`. The table contains a single row:

`{ id: 1, producer: "Ford", model: "Focus" }`

When I update it the following way:

```
new_car = Car(id=1, producer="Fiat")
session.merge(new_car)
```

The result is:

`{ id: 1, producer: "Fiat", model: "Focus" }`

However, when `model` is set explicitly to `None` in the construtor:

```
new_car = Car(id=1, producer="Fiat", model=None)
session.merge(new_car)
```

The result is:

`{ id: 1, producer: "Fiat", model: NULL }`

Why the behavior of merge is different when `None` value is set explicity?

Answer (score 1):

Because generally speaking, you actually need a way to differentiate "set value to NULL" from "don't change value".